# NodeJS: Can't return a result from a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, search, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to return the result from this function :

```js
var YouTube = require('youtube-node');
var youTube = new YouTube();

youTube.setKey('XXXXXXXXXXXX');

var result = youTube.search('World War z Trailer', 2, 
    function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            return result
        }})

console.log(result)
```

But then I only get undefined as a result in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the response.

This simple answer is to place the `console.log(result)` inside the callback.

Or you can wrap the `search` method in a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```js
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    youTube.search('World War z Trailer', 2, function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
        else {
            resolve(result);
        }
    })
});
```

Then you can wait for the response using `.then()` like this:

```js
promise.then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Or using [await/async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await):

```js
(async () => {
    try {
        const result = await promise;
        console.log(result);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
})();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62154801/13662223 thank you it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Last function here is a callback function, it doesn't return value in way you want. Read how it works somewhere, for example [here](https://javascript.info/callbacks). 
Your issue could be resolved with Promise in this way

```js
var search = new Promise(
  (resolve, reject) => {
    youTube.search('World War z Trailer', 2, function(error, result) {
     if (error) { reject(error); }
     resolve(result);
    })
  }
);       
(async () => {
  var result = await search;
  console.log(result);
})()
```